# The right ASP.NET boilerplate best practice

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I just found about the [ASP.NET boilerplate](https://aspnetboilerplate.com) framework for ASP.NET Core applications. The boilerplate is cool, it has all the necessary structure we need in order to create a SOLID proof web application.

My question is that, as per the site I have to create entity models in .Core project, and Dto's in Application project but as I can see these Question, and Answers are different entities but they kept both of them in the same folder and same namespace.

It does not look like a good practice, can anyone tell me is it wrong to keep these related entities in the same namespace/folder or it's ok to do so?

[image]

Comment: Can the dude who flagged for closing care to tell me why it needs to be closed?

Comment: There may be many answers to this question, but an `Answer` cannot exist without a `Question`.

Comment: If I can go on with that analogy, a fully user entity integrated application will have full reference to all related entities. then should all entities be in the same folder or namespace. Because without the user none of them can exist?

Comment: Woah, that's a long shot.

Comment: @Kirk it's not good practice. if your project has 100+ tables, what will happen? you will be lost in namespace references

Comment: BTW, this template is for commercial use, but all code is not public except the 2 projects you are using. it's not a open source project at all, don't dig in more. I provide you another version, which I have been using for years, but you have to maintenance update by yourself: https://rehansaeed.com/asp-net-mvc-boilerplate/

Comment: @aaron I know right, but just saying. But I get it, it's a typical cardinality for an entity.

Comment: @Dongdong Is it? I thought they have a separate version for commercial use called Asp.net Zero! you might wanna check that out!

Comment: @Kirk: Question is **primarily opinion-based**, 
_Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise_ See see [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on how to ask a good (and on-topic) question. Questions asking for opinions (or causing highly opinionated answers) are off-topic. And best practices tend to create opinionated answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can locate entities/services into any namespace. This is not related to the framework actually.

Question/Answer application is very simple project where there are just 2 entities. I thought that Question is aggregate root and answer is a child entity (they are a single aggregate together). This is why I put them into same namespace.

I suggest to follow "namespace per aggregate" principle, but "namespace per entity" is also fine.

BTW, @Dongdone, AspNet Boilerplate is completely open source & free. We have a another product, AspNet Zero (https://aspnetzero.com) that is commerical and developed on top of the ABP framework. But that does not make the ABP framework a paid tool. It's absolutely open source & free.